# Javascript (strict) errors in Safari and Firefox with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script, safari

I have the following javascript function that prevents form submission if all required fields are not complete and is part of a form I am creating using Google Apps Scripts. Note that the #submitbutton is actually a regular button and Google Apps Scripts forces strict javascript. The script works fine on chrome, but when I test it on Safari or Firefox, it doesn't appear to be running. Am I using a method that only works on Chrome? Am I missing something here?

I get the following errors in Safari: 
`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '(1, $)('#submitbutton')')` and `Uncaught Strict mode does not allow function declarations in a lexically nested statement.`

Firefox gives a similar issue: `Uncaught in strict mode code, functions may be declared only at top level or immediately within another function 2699307207-maestro_htmlapp_bin_maestro_htmlapp.js:84:360` and `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#submitbutton').on('click', function() {
   $(this).val("Submitting...");
   //check for required fields
   var emptyFields = $('[required]').filter(function() {
       $(this).removeClass("warning");
       if ($(this).val().length === 0){
         $(this).addClass("warning")
         return true
       } else {
         return false
       }
   });

   if (emptyFields.length === 0) {
       $(this).prop('disabled', true);
       document.getElementById('incompleteWarning').style.display = 'none';
       document.getElementById('bePatient').style.display = 'inline';
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded).uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
    } else{
      $(this).val("Submit Application")
      document.getElementById('incompleteWarning').style.display = 'inline';
      document.getElementById('incompleteWarning').style.color = 'red';
    }
});
</script>
```

jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/hofresre/

Note that the jsfiddle doesn't use the google.script, but replaces it with this.parentNode.submit()

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Per comments:

Line 84 of maestro_htmlapp_bin_maestro_htmlapp.js:84:360: 
`function ys(a){for(var b=[],c=0;c<a.length;++c){var d=a[c];b[c]=Mn(d)?(new String(d)).toString():d}return b}var As=[vh,"[object Object]"];var Bs=["alert",ts(function(a){return alert(a)},16,[4]),"confirm",ts(function(a){return confirm(a)},16,[4]),"prompt",ts(function(a,b){return prompt(a,b)},16,[4,4])];var Cs=window.console&&window.console.error?function(a){window.console.error(a)}:void 0,Ds=window.console&&window.console.info?function(a){window.console.info(a)}:void 0,Es=window.console&&window.console.log?function(a){window.console.log(a)}:void 0,Fs=window.console&&window.console.warn?function(a){window.console.warn(a)}:void 0,Gs=["console.debug",ts(window.console&&window.console.debug?function(a){window.console.debug(a)}:void 0,16,[4]),"console.error",ts(Cs,16,[4]),"console.info",ts(Ds,16,[4]),`

Comment: with firefox can you show us the line `maestro_htmlapp_bin_maestro_htmlapp.js:84:360` ?

Comment: @arsel, You just wanted line 84? I attached it to the original post. Excuse my ignorance if this is not what you were requesting.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you know that browser don't support web functionalities the same way. We know that google always focalize their web library and their support firstly for chrome browser.

When you just have this error:

> functions can only be declared at top level or immediately within another function

You must not put a function declaration inside any other block, like an *if-statement* or *for-loop*; cause any block scope that use curly braces: *try-catch-finally*, *if-else if-else*, *for*, *switch*, and *ES6* also define new feature that utilize block scope such as class.

you can't: `"use strict" { Function bar(){/****/} }`

Therefore, independents solutions that i can provide are:

- Find if there is a version of script (here google script or JQuery) (which is recent) where this problem have been solved.
- You can also comment `"use strict"` in the corresponding script (for example in google script).
- Make show that you first include google script and JQuery before the other js scripts.
- Try to use non minified script library because something (an example which append with JQuery 1.11) it's the cause of the problem.

Before trying previous solutions, maybe this modified code can work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var trySubmission = function() {
 $(this).val("Submitting...");
 //check for required fields
 var emptyFields = $('[required]').filter(function() {
   $(this).removeClass("warning");
   if ($(this).val().length === 0){
     $(this).addClass("warning")
     return true
   } else {
     return false
   }
 });

 if (emptyFields.length === 0) {
   $(this).prop('disabled', true);
   document.getElementById('incompleteWarning').style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById('bePatient').style.display = 'inline';
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded).uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
 } else{
  $(this).val("Submit Application")
  document.getElementById('incompleteWarning').style.display = 'inline';
  document.getElementById('incompleteWarning').style.color = 'red';
 } ;
}

$('#submitbutton').on('click', trySubmission ) ;

</script>
```

Comment: I'm developing in Google Apps Script so I can't change the fact that they force strict javascript in their HTML service. I tried changing to the code you suggested and it didn't work; I still got both errors. `<!-- Load jQuery Library-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` is the jQuery that I'm using at the top of my html page and all user defined functions are at the bottom. I'm not really familiar with minification and not sure if the jQuery library I'm using is minified or not.

Comment: your jQuery library is minified cause the presence of *.min.* before the extension.

Answer (score 0):

What mode are you loading the HTML as from the GS file?

When in SandboxMode.NATIVE the error occurs in SandboxMode.IFRAME things seem to work

Here is some test code for a GS file

```
function doGet(e) {
   var html= HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("test.html");   
   return html.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

...and the HTML as test.html

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

   function myFunction() {

    if (jQuery) {  
     // jQuery is loaded  
       console.log( "Loaded" );
     } else {
     // jQuery is not loaded
      console.log( "Not Loaded" );
     }
     $("#message").html("Something happened.");
   }

   $(document).ready(myFunction);

</script>
<p id="message">Nothing happened. </p>
```